# How to user stored procedure to fulfill update & create record operations by input parameters values in java ReSTful web services

Tags: java, mysql, rest, stored-procedures, bad-request

I'm trying to create web service to create & update user using same stored procedure, for that i'm passing following input through ReST client

```
{
"user_id": "23",
"user_email_id": "a@a.a",
"user_password": "fdsdsdf",
"firstname": "sdfsdf",
"lastname": "sfdsdfds",
"mobile_number": "1234567890",
"user_status": 1,
"isdeleted": 0,
"created_by": 1,
"profile_picturename": "kfksdjfhksjd",
"address": "sfdsdfsd"
}
```

& my JDBC code is as

```
try {
        connection = this.getConnection();
        callableStatement = connection
                .prepareCall("{ call sp_user_upsert(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) } ");

        // this.setIntToCallableStatement("pv_user_id",
        // userInputModel.getUser_id());

        if (userInputModel.getUser_id() != null) {
            if (!(userInputModel.getUser_id().toString().isEmpty()))
                callableStatement.setInt("pv_user_id",
                        userInputModel.getUser_id());
            else
                callableStatement.setString("pv_user_id", "");

        } else {
            callableStatement.setString("pv_user_id", "");
        }
        callableStatement.setString("pv_user_email_id",
                userInputModel.getUser_email_id());
```

I'm able to update user record, but if i'm trying to create new user with parameters

```
{
"user_id": "",
"user_email_id": "a@a.a",
"user_password": "fdsdsdf",
"firstname": "sdfsdf",
"lastname": "sfdsdfds",
"mobile_number": "1234567890",
"user_status": 1,
"isdeleted": 0,
"created_by": 1,
"profile_picturename": "kfksdjfhksjd",
"address": "sfdsdfsd"
}
```

to create an new record, its showing HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request status on rest client,

Can anyone help me to solve this problem or any good suggestions to create an user

I'm using MySql DB

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the code for your `sp_user_upsert` procedure? Also, do you have any logs/stack traces from the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to answer this without knowing the stored procedure and the DB system you are using.

My guess is that you fill a String for the unknown user_id, but an int if it is known. Some DBs check the type signature to resolve the stored procedure and you might simply get an error "SP not found because of pv_user_id being a String. Try to put 0, -1 or set the parameter to null.

Comment: I'm using MySql DB & if pass userid as null or "", ReST client is showing 400 Bad Request with message "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect", still facing same problem